# Is there a way to set the default developer profile in xcode?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

Our company has 2 developer accounts.  The Enterprise account, and our public iTunesConnect developer account.

Since these 2 cannot intermingle, I now have 2 developer profiles:

FirstName LastName (enterpriseId)
FirstName LastName (publicId)

We normally like to keep the build settings at "iPhone Developer", however, since the creation of the 2nd account (thus profile), it defaults to the public profile, but I would like it to default to my Enterprise profile.

Is there a way to change this?

If it's going by app id, it's probably getting confused that both profiles have a wildcard id of com.companyname.*  would the best way to fix this is to create something like net.companyname.* (internal) and com.companyname.* (public) ?